# Weird error using DatePicker, Calendar Constructor fails?

Tags: datepicker, sapui5

I am working on a SAPUI5 application at my company (so I cannot post much example) and I am having problems using the `DatePicker`. I have defined it in the XML in a normal way (see below) using the `sap.m` namespace. It all works well in the development server. The problem is when it is transported to the testing server the popup calendar causes an error (see below) to occur. This error does not occur in the development server ever. To be specific, **the cause of the error** is the button next to the input field that lets you pick from a mini-calendar.

A strange event I noticed is that if I open the mini-calendar in a different view it'll work in the view where I am having problems.

If anyone has seen something similar to this or knows anything that could help me solve this problem, please let me know. The error all comes from built-in libraries and not from my written code.

The XML file

```
<DatePicker id="blah blah" width="70%" value="blah blah"
            editable="blah blah" 
            valueFormat="YYYY-MM-dd" change="ValidateDate" />
```

The error in the console:

```
MonthRenderer.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: m.getLegend is not a function
    at Object.M.getDayHelper (MonthRenderer.js:6)
    at Object.M.renderDays (MonthRenderer.js:6)
    at Object.M.renderMonth (MonthRenderer.js:6)
    at Object.M.render (MonthRenderer.js:6)
    at constructor.R.renderControl (sap-ui-core.js:1089)
    at I.renderControl (sap-ui-core.js:457)
    at Object.C.render (CalendarRenderer.js:6)
    at constructor.R.renderControl (sap-ui-core.js:1089)
    at constructor.R.render (sap-ui-core.js:1093)
    at I.render (sap-ui-core.js:457)
```

EDIT:

See @Developer post below. It appears that when the library calls the Calendar constructor, it does not include a `getLegend()` method. On his post below, you can see that his function is defined but when I do the same thing on my test server the function comes up as undefined. How is this possible???

Comment: Well, is m.getLegend a function? Are you calling it as you would a function? What is m? You're going to have to post a bit of code. We can't guess what the problem is...

Comment: The error arises all from built-in libraries. MonthRenderer and every other class mentioned in the error message is not part of the code I wrote. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Can you confirm if dev and quality systems are using the same version of UI5 ?

Comment: Good call Rahul. I've had issues in the past because of that.

Comment: Thanks for the comments mates. I have checked the version in both systems using `sap.ui.version` in the console while the apps are running. Both are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the line where the `getLegend()` function is created, you may want to investigate the constructor for the `Calendar` class.

[image]

Comment: Will look at it and get back

Comment: Try loading the `sap.ui.unified` library before using it in the Datepicker.